# Can't able to connect my service to ignite cluster

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ignite, apacheignite

i have two servers A and B and my service s. Ignite node running on server A.
when i run my service on server B first and then on Server A my both instance of service connect smoothly but when i run my service on server A first and then on B it show me error
i.e : "Joining persistence node to in-memory cluster couldn't be allowed due to baseline auto-adjust is enabled and timeout equal to 0"

How to resolve it i want run two instance of my services smoothly

Comment: Is it on purpose, having in-mem node and a persistent one inside the same cluster?

Comment: I suppose the error message is self-descriptive, but that mixed persistent setup is not recommended.

Comment: the node is persistent

Comment: Let me modify the question to clarify the nature of services :
I have ignite (server nodes) running on Server A and some services (client nodes) that can run on Server A or B. Now when 
i run some of the client nodes on Server B first and remaining on Server A then everything works fine but when i try reverse (first deploy client nodes on Server A) it fails to join cluster topology throwing error "Joining persistence node to in-memory cluster couldn't be allowed due to baseline auto-adjust is enabled and timeout equal to 0"

and baseline-auto-adjust enabled